# How can I open the drawerLayout on activity start?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, drawerlayout

I would like to have an Activity that stars with the drawer layout open at the beginning. I have tried simply putting

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(gravity.END());
```

in various places in my code but regardless the items become unclickable until I close and re-open the drawer.

Has anyone had any luck with this? It is mostly for user experience reasons to add this feature.

My Drawer Layout has a list view in it, which clicks change my RecyclerView in the activity.

Here is my XML file for anyone who might need it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:orientation="vertical">


<!--android:elevation="4dp"-->
<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar2">



        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/listview2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:dividerHeight="8dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_white_24dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:elevation="24dp"
            app:fabSize="auto"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/listview2"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
            app:rippleColor="#FFF" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do like this in your `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` of `Activity`:

```
    mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        }
    }, 200);
```

Comment: This is great too because now the user can see the animation of the drawer opening rather than it just being open when it starts.